# Multiple test case in c program not working

Tags: c

I was writing a program in C to check how many elements in a given array are smaller than or equal to a particular element of same array.

`t` = no of test cases
`n` = size of array
`k` = index of that element array with with whom all the elements have to be compare
`j` = number of elements less than or equal to element `k` of array

```
for (i = 1; i <= t; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (l = 1; l <= n; l++)
    {
        if (arr[l] <= arr[k])
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", j);
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

But the problem is that my program is running only for one case. After that it terminates.
Why this is happening? Why this is not running for 2, 3, 4 ... test cases?

Comment: Arrays are indexed from `0` to `length-1`. `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) is not reliable in general — though it may work OK for you if you work on Windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any alternative for fflush(stdin)?

Comment: Lots; they're detailed in the linked SO Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outer loop using the variable `i` and an inner loop also using (and modifying) the same variable `i`. When the inner loop has completed I assume `i` is left greater than `t` so the outer loop also ends. This bug might have been easier to avoid if you had used more meaningful variable names.

Here is your code trimmed down to show the problem:

```
for (i = 1; i <= t; i++)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    }
}
```